How to save the selected option to Api Vue3
I want to save the option that the user pick in the select box. I want to get the value and the text but don't know how to do it? My code is:
<div>
<select>
  <option v-for="item in subjects" :value="item.value">
    {{ item.text }}
  </option>
</select>
<button @click="saveOption">Save</button>

import { ref } from 'vue'

const formData = ref({
choosenOption: '',
} as optionData)

const saveOption = async (): Promise<void> => {
 const res = await api.put(formData.value, session)
  if (res.error) {
  console.log('Did not save')
  }
  formData.choosenOption.subjects = ''
 }

const subjects = ref([
 { value: 1, text: 'Option 1' },
 { value: 2, text: 'Option 2' },
 { value: 3, text: 'Option 3' },
])


Here is an example of how you can get the select value from the official docs. Does this help ?

Yes I have looked at that one, but I don't know how to get it when you press save and it saves to the api..?

I posted an answer with how it should be, the general idea, if you need something or have more questions feel free to ask.

You can store the selected value in a ref then use it later on save to get the value, I used the formData here since it was in the code already :
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

const formData = ref({
choosenOption: '',
} as optionData)

const saveOption = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const selectedSubject = formData.value.choosenOption;
  console.log("the value will be :" , selectedSubject);
  // call your api here with the data
 }

const subjects = ref([
 { value: 1, text: 'Option 1' },
 { value: 2, text: 'Option 2' },
 { value: 3, text: 'Option 3' },
]);
</script>

<template>
<select v-model="formData.choosenOption">
  <option v-for="item in subjects" :value="item.value">
    {{ item.text }}
  </option>
</select>
<button @click="saveOption">Save</button>
</template>

